# Filtering data frame using distance

Tags: python

I have a dataframe where ID represents cells in a drosophila embryo, X and Y are the coordinates of these cell and mRNA is the number of a specific mRNA per each cell.

```
       ID        X        Y  mRNA
0        0  149.492  189.153     0
1        1  115.084  194.082     2
2        2  135.331  194.831     7
3        3  136.965  184.493     2
4        4  124.025  190.069     1
...    ...      ...      ...   ...
```

I am calculating the distance of this matrix using the following code:
(I got lots of help for this in another question [Pandas Dataframe iterate over rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365842/pandas-dataframe-iterate-over-rows))

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.spatial as spsp

df_1 =pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv', sep=',')
coords = df_1[['X', 'Y']].to_numpy()
distances = spsp.distance_matrix(coords, coords)
df_1['dist'] = distances.tolist()

print(df_1)
        ID        X  ...  mRNA                                               dist
0        0  194.856  ...     0  [0.0, 10.71542532986913, 41.123199608007155, 3...
1        1  196.222  ...     0  [10.71542532986913, 0.0, 39.8050943724544, 27....
2        2  156.695  ...     0  [41.123199608007155, 39.8050943724544, 0.0, 13...
3        3  169.690  ...     0  [30.83865321313498, 27.490533643419877, 13.233...
4        4  188.193  ...     0  [15.614038875319903, 8.7559060068048, 31.52100...
...    ...      ...  ...   ...                                                ...
```

Thats good, however, what I would really like is not the column **dist** to appear, but instead use the distance to calculate another column where the mRNA values for any cells with distance < 10 is shown.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you supposed to be comparing against `dist` or `distances`? `dist` is a list of values, and distances looks like a matrix so whats are do you want to compare the 10 against? The length of the list/matrix or a specific value in the list/matrix?

Comment: Ideally I wouldn't want to print the column dist at all, but instead print a column with the mRNA values of the cells (IDs) for whom dist < 10.

Comment: dist is a list so what are you comparing the 10 against? the length of the list or a specific value in the list?

Comment: For each value on the list smaller than 10, I want the mRNA value associated to it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider first migrating list values to columns then [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) data from wide to long format for proper comparison of *mRNA* and distances. Finally filter records for needed distance criteria, leaving out zeroes which were coords compared to itself:

```
# ... SAME AS ABOVE ...

# CREATES d0, d1, d2, d3, ... COLUMNS
dist_cols = ['d'+str(i) for i in range(len(df_1['Y']))]
df_1[dist_cols] = df_1['dist'].apply(pd.Series)

# RESHAPE DATA LONG
melted_df = df_1.melt(id_vars = ['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'mRNA'], 
                      value_vars = dist_cols, 
                      var_name = 'dist', value_name = 'dist_val')

# FILTER FOR DISTANCES (0, 10)
melted_df = melted_df[melted_df['dist_val'].between(0, 10, inclusive = False)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried and I got this error:    value_vars = dist_names,
NameError: name 'dist_names' is not defined

Comment: Should it be this instead?
``` 
melted_df = df_1.melt(id_vars = ['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'mRNA'],
                      value_vars = dist_cols,
                      var_name = 'dist', value_name = 'dist_val')
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry for mis-type. Yes, your correction should work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your data, but if the 'dist' column has what you want, then you can filter your data.

Like this,

```
 df_1 = df_1[df_1.dist<10]
```

will remove all rows with 'dist' greater than 10.

```
print(df_1.head())
```

Update:
Since your 'dist' column is list itself, we need to get each element separately.  To get an individual element, say the 0 element (first):

```
df=df[df.b.str[0]<10]
```

Comment: sorry.  I edited the above code, to be: df_1 = df_1[df_1.dist<10] and should return a new dataframe with all rows removed for 'dist' greater than 10.

Comment: Still not working, I thinks is because dist is a list
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Ahh, your 'dist' is a list of values for each row.  Which element of that list is the distance?  You can get each element of that list.  I'll add an update above, that looks like this df=df[df.b.str[0]<10] will compare the 0 element of 'dist' on each row to 10.